# Animated gifs not restarting in Firefox (with examples)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, caching

### Description of Problem:

Animated gifs don't appear to restart properly in Firefox under many circumstances. This is an issue I only experience in Mozilla and with no other browser.

For example, why does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqQY/123/) work to always restart it, but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqQY/124/) does not? In the latter, the gif is clearly cached and looping forever in the background, so when you call .show() it will appear at some random point in the middle of the animation.

How can I achieve what I'm attempting to do in the second Fiddle and force the gif to restart each time I hide it? And no, I don't want to redownload the entire gif every single time, so appending `'?random=' + Date.now()` to the image is not a solution.

### Code from [Link #1](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqQY/123/):

```
$('#still, #animated').click(function() {
    animated.attr('src', "");
    animated.attr('src', srcToGif);
});
```

### Code from [Link #2](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqQY/124/):

```
$('#still, #animated').click(function() {
    if (!clicked) {
        clicked = 1;
        animated.attr('src', "");
        animated.attr('src', srcToGif);
        animated.show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            animated.hide();
            clicked = 0;
        }, 9500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean to do this ?- http://jsfiddle.net/QSZ23/2/

Comment: I want the gif to complete fully once on each click (hence the flag), and then hide itself so the still image is on top again. Then once the still image is clicked again, restart the gif from the beginning. It is very clearly cached because even in your example, if you play around with it enough, you can observe the gif starting from a random point after the click. For comparison and to see how it should work, visit my second link in Chrome or IE.

Comment: I think I'm with you ( but would be tricky I guess as 9500 might not always co-incide with the browser framerate ( could be cpu high at the time for example ) - does this example give any more ideas ? - http://jsfiddle.net/4L2nS/2/

Comment: Another to try with help with the caching ( as not seeing it here - enough to say ) - http://jsfiddle.net/3gaAM/3/ ( hope I am helping )

Comment: (Those tries all failing) might be best to split the frames up of the gif as separate images and then animate through them manually.

Comment: There is just no rhyme or reason to how Firefox is treating it. I wish I had ideas but I'm fresh out.

Comment: It appears to be a decades old bug in Firefox. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129986

Comment: Ugh, even worse is that if you test the files locally, it works flawlessly like the other browsers. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`animated.attr('src', "");`

with

`animated.removeAttribute('src');`

Works for me in Firefox 30.
Assuming the word `animated` is a normal, non-jquery-specific `img` reference.

I don't do js libraries in general because I want to have control. The minification is often illusory due to the bulk of the library and when a quirk does occur, it's hard to troubleshoot.